# Installing GCC-13 on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, c++20

Has anyone successfully installed gcc-13 on Ubuntu 22.04?  Looking to use some newer C++20 features that do not appear to be supported on the current default build (gcc-11.3)

There does not appear to be any packages available at this point,  so I am guessing there is a correct install procedure for Ubuntu.  I did find some but I wanted to know if there are any that have been successful for others.

Comment: Just upgrade to lunar aka Ubuntu 23.04, or use it in Docker.  [It has it](https://packages.ubuntu.com/lunar/g++-13).  Being on an LTS means you value stability.  Desiring the newest compiler means you want new stuff.  You need to make a choice,

Comment: (There is/was a PPA with builds and backports I have used in the past but it doesn't _always_ have all one wants. See https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/ubuntu/ppa )

Comment: I have had success building my own gcc-13 on Ubuntu Jammy 22.04.2. Check out my GitHub script. https://github.com/slyfox1186/script-repo/blob/main/shell/installers/build-gcc

Comment: I think this question would be on-topic on Ubuntu Stackexchange. And it's ridiculous that the new major release of the mainstream compiler is not available on the most mainstream OS.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Being on LTS means, I value stability of the OS, not stability of the tools.

Comment: @tommsch So then you value the older compiler and it's stability.  Again, you expressed a tradeoff.  I have found for these fifteen or so years of using Ubuntu that I like the combination of stability _and freshness / currentness_ of tools that I get with bi-annual upgrades.  So I am on 23.04 now and will be on 23.10.  Works for me.  If and when I need more bleeding edge things or variants, I often use a container.  But I already recommended both approaches in May so we are going in circles here.